# How to hide shipping and billing address from checkout page as per quote value

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-address

As per my project requirement, I need to hide the address field for quote data.

when ($quote->getDeliveryMethod=='curbside') //custom data saving properly in quote table.

Anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in short you need to modify or add layoutProcessor
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Comment: I want to remove address filed not add

Comment: layoutProcessor does not mean it always adds a new attribute
This is just an example, of layoutProcessor, it could be also used to modify existing attributes, 
Just access the array with your attribute_code as it is done to create the custom_attribute, but without the whole model stuff, if the attribute does exist it should be there, and access the visible field and set it to false